# asset() function in symfony3 does not convert url

Tags: php, symfony, web, controller, twig

I want to load pictures dynamically from database.

Here's the table containing the image informations:

[image: table]

**Controller code**

```
public function listeproductAction()
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $img = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:image')->findAll();
    return $this->render('lucky/images.html.twig', array(
        'img' => $img ,

    ));

}
```

**twig code**

```
{% for im in img %}
 <img src="{{ asset('/uploads/brochures/' ~  im.getBrochure()) }} ">
{% endfor %}
```

**result**

```
<div class="main-content">
        <img src="/uploads/brochures/0fa58c757752ced32d04b57bb7fa0d65.png ">
    </div>
```

The problem is that `asset` function doesn't find the image.

Comment: Where is the image stored?

Comment: web/uploads/brochures

Comment: Assuming /web/ is your webroot, your url is correct, so I don't see the problem.

Comment: When I use {% image%}, the file path will be changed in the result and the name of the image will change too, But when I use Asset nothing changed ?